# TextView Numbers shown in English in Persian font

Tags: java, android, fonts, locale, right-to-left

I am loading a string which contains some number (all in Persian) into an android TextView. Everything was fine until I changed my custom font, numbers of text shown as English number.

```
Expected : ۱۲۳۴
Received : 1234
```

I know that my new font support Persian number. When I change the number locale using code below the number shown correctly.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("fa", "IR"));
String newNumber = numberFormat.format(number);
```

The problem is I have a string and it's hard to find the numeric part and change it. also my previous font works fine and I can't understand what's the problem with this font.

Any Idea how to globally solve this problem for all textview, or at least for a string?

Comment: Did you test my answer? It will help you to convert numbers in your string from English to Persian.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali thanks for your answer, It works and I give +1 to it, but I was looking for a logical solution, not a replacement. anyway, I solve the problem by changing the font to Persian numeric one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use this method:

```
private String setPersianNumbers(String str) {
    return str
            .replace("0", "۰")
            .replace("1", "۱")
            .replace("2", "۲")
            .replace("3", "۳")
            .replace("4", "۴")
            .replace("5", "۵")
            .replace("6", "۶")
            .replace("7", "۷")
            .replace("8", "۸")
            .replace("9", "۹");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
 String NumberString = String.format("%d", NumberInteger);
```

123 will become ١٢٣

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for show Hegira date in Persian number:

```
    String farsiDate = "1398/11/3";
    farsiDate = farsiDate
            .replace('0', '٠')
            .replace('1', '١')
            .replace('2', '٢')
            .replace('3', '٣')
            .replace('4', '٤')
            .replace('5', '٥')
            .replace('6', '٦')
            .replace('7', '٧')
            .replace('8', '٨')
            .replace('9', '٩');
    dateText.setText(farsiDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to translate it yourself.  TextFormat does not automatically translate from arabic digits to any other language's, because that's actually not what people usually want.  Each of those digits have their own character codes, a simple walk of the string and replacing them with the appropriate persian code would be sufficient.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how the previous font work correctly and show the Persian numbers? is there any kind of translation for a string with number?

Comment: A custom font could have defined the arabic numerals to look like persian ones.  A custom font can define the letter A to draw as a Q if it wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String[] persianNumbers = new String[]{ "۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹" };

public static String PerisanNumber(String text) {
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    String out = "";
    int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
            out += persianNumbers[number];
        } else if (c == '٫') {
            out += '،';
        } else {
            out += c;
        }
    }
    return out;
}}
```

and after that u can use it like below vlock

```
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText(PersianDigitConverter.PerisanNumber("این یک نمونه است ۱۲ "));
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you can use the function below:

```
function toPersianDigits(inputValue: any) {
  let value = `${inputValue}`;
  const charCodeZero = '۰'.charCodeAt(0);
  return String(value).replace(/[0-9]/g, w =>
    String.fromCharCode(w.charCodeAt(0) + charCodeZero - 48),
  );
 }

export {toPersianDigits};
```